# How to include Skydrive folders in FolderPicker, in a "Windows Store" (Metro) app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, onedrive

I can see the local folders with the FolderPicker, but the Skydrive ones don't show up. How do I include them?

edit: for what it's worth, here's my code:

```
    async private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var picker = new FolderPicker();
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation=PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.ViewMode=PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    }
```

edit 2: The *FilePicker* does show Skydrive. But then I can't pick a folder, so that's no help.

Comment: They should be there by default. No special action should be required.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Yes, Soner, I have a C# Metro app that works, I can select folders using the FolderPicker - but it only show the local folders. I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: Do you have SkyDrive app installed and working?

Comment: Yes, the SkyDrive app is installed - it works both in Metro and in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I'll keep on experimenting and I'll post an answer if I figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that FolderPicker is simply broken out of the box. Perhaps the only way to enumerate a Skydrive folder is to use their "REST" API... I hope not.

Answer (score 1):

The skydrive is there by default, just click the "Files" drop down list, then click skydrive.

Edit

Sorry, I misread your question as file picker.

When you ask for a storage folder you basically ask ask for permission to all the files in that folder, which skydrive couldn't provide without downloading all the files to a local cache - this is impractical due to the time it could take.

Why will a filepicker not work for you?

Comment: I wish! It's there in other apps (e.g. Skitch), but in my app the list ends with "Network", and there is no "Skydrive" icon.

Comment: The app needs to be told of a location where to load many files, so a folder picker would be the right thing to do, if it worked. The thing is, by using the Live APIs it's possible to find folders and enumerate them, so it appears that one could re-implement a working folder picker for Skydrive, if one had the time and desire.